# How to use "left_join" with multiple columns within the same dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, for-loop, dplyr

I have the following dataframes:

```
# df1

df1 = data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2002-01-01"), as.Date("2021-01-28"), by = "day"), stringsAsFactors = F)

# df2

df2 = structure(list(Date...1 = structure(c(1107129600, 1109548800, 
1112227200, 1114732800, 1117497600, 1120089600, 1122595200, 1125446400, 
1128038400, 1130716800, 1133308800, 1135900800, 1138665600, 1141084800, 
1143763200, 1146182400, 1149033600, 1151625600, 1154304000, 1156982400
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), GDPWY = c(103.2165, 
101.6228, 102.5635, 104.9937, 107.2693, 109.6424, 108.757, 111.1982, 
111.4118, 109.063, 109.1665, 112.1265, 110.0442, 110.4361, 106.8804, 
104.4279, 104.2291, 103.6855, 105.7539, 108.4851), Date...3 = structure(c(1083024000, 
1083196800, 1083283200, 1083628800, 1083715200, 1083801600, 1083888000, 
1084147200, 1084233600, 1084320000, 1084406400, 1084492800, 1084752000, 
1084838400, 1084924800, 1085011200, 1085097600, 1085356800, 1085443200, 
1085529600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    X5Y5YINFSWAP = c(2.41, 2.43, 2.43, 2.43, 2.44, 2.46, 2.48, 
    2.45, 2.48, 2.53, 2.53, 2.55, 2.55, 2.54, 2.55, 2.6, 2.6, 
    2.6, 2.58, 2.59), Date...5 = structure(c(1190592000, 1190678400, 
    1190764800, 1190851200, 1190937600, 1191196800, 1191283200, 
    1191369600, 1191456000, 1191542400, 1191801600, 1191888000, 
    1191974400, 1192060800, 1192147200, 1192406400, 1192492800, 
    1192579200, 1192665600, 1192752000), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), ITBONDSWAPBREAK1Y = c(0.161, 0.146, 
    0.2, 0.248, 0.273, 0.256, 0.29, 0.281, 0.298, 0.318, 0.414, 
    0.342, 0.348, 0.372, 0.279, 0.291, 0.732, 0.539, 0.543, 0.308
    ), Date...7 = structure(c(1279843200, 1280102400, 1280188800, 
    1280275200, 1280361600, 1280448000, 1280707200, 1280793600, 
    1280880000, 1280966400, 1281052800, 1311120000, 1311206400, 
    1311292800, 1311552000, 1311638400, 1311724800, 1311811200, 
    1311897600, 1312156800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    FRBONDSWAPBREAK1Y = c(0.958, 0.955, 0.941, 0.937, 0.947, 
    1.008, 1.039, 1.065, 1.031, 1.049, 1.069, 2.564, 2.559, 2.626, 
    2.659, 2.608, 2.61, 2.679, 2.71, 2.597), Date...9 = structure(c(1159315200, 
    1159401600, 1159488000, 1159747200, 1159833600, 1159920000, 
    1160006400, 1160092800, 1160352000, 1160438400, 1160524800, 
    1160611200, 1160697600, 1160956800, 1161043200, 1161129600, 
    1161216000, 1161302400, 1161561600, 1161648000), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), ITBONDSWAPBREAK2Y = c(0.11, 0.117, 
    0.12, 0.144, 0.151, 0.114, 0.174, 0.156, 0.174, 0.167, 0.193, 
    0.182, 0.186, 0.207, 0.201, 0.196, 0.206, 0.199, 0.201, 0.199
    )), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

     Date...1    GDPWY   Date...3 X5Y5YINFSWAP
1  2005-01-31 103.2165 2004-04-27         2.41
2  2005-02-28 101.6228 2004-04-29         2.43
3  2005-03-31 102.5635 2004-04-30         2.43
4  2005-04-29 104.9937 2004-05-04         2.43
5  2005-05-31 107.2693 2004-05-05         2.44
6  2005-06-30 109.6424 2004-05-06         2.46
7  2005-07-29 108.7570 2004-05-07         2.48
8  2005-08-31 111.1982 2004-05-10         2.45
9  2005-09-30 111.4118 2004-05-11         2.48
10 2005-10-31 109.0630 2004-05-12         2.53
11 2005-11-30 109.1665 2004-05-13         2.53
12 2005-12-30 112.1265 2004-05-14         2.55
13 2006-01-31 110.0442 2004-05-17         2.55
14 2006-02-28 110.4361 2004-05-18         2.54
15 2006-03-31 106.8804 2004-05-19         2.55
16 2006-04-28 104.4279 2004-05-20         2.60
17 2006-05-31 104.2291 2004-05-21         2.60
18 2006-06-30 103.6855 2004-05-24         2.60
19 2006-07-31 105.7539 2004-05-25         2.58
20 2006-08-31 108.4851 2004-05-26         2.59
     Date...5 ITBONDSWAPBREAK1Y   Date...7
1  2007-09-24             0.161 2010-07-23
2  2007-09-25             0.146 2010-07-26
3  2007-09-26             0.200 2010-07-27
4  2007-09-27             0.248 2010-07-28
5  2007-09-28             0.273 2010-07-29
6  2007-10-01             0.256 2010-07-30
7  2007-10-02             0.290 2010-08-02
8  2007-10-03             0.281 2010-08-03
9  2007-10-04             0.298 2010-08-04
10 2007-10-05             0.318 2010-08-05
11 2007-10-08             0.414 2010-08-06
12 2007-10-09             0.342 2011-07-20
13 2007-10-10             0.348 2011-07-21
14 2007-10-11             0.372 2011-07-22
15 2007-10-12             0.279 2011-07-25
16 2007-10-15             0.291 2011-07-26
17 2007-10-16             0.732 2011-07-27
18 2007-10-17             0.539 2011-07-28
19 2007-10-18             0.543 2011-07-29
20 2007-10-19             0.308 2011-08-01
   FRBONDSWAPBREAK1Y   Date...9 ITBONDSWAPBREAK2Y
1              0.958 2006-09-27             0.110
2              0.955 2006-09-28             0.117
3              0.941 2006-09-29             0.120
4              0.937 2006-10-02             0.144
5              0.947 2006-10-03             0.151
6              1.008 2006-10-04             0.114
7              1.039 2006-10-05             0.174
8              1.065 2006-10-06             0.156
9              1.031 2006-10-09             0.174
10             1.049 2006-10-10             0.167
11             1.069 2006-10-11             0.193
12             2.564 2006-10-12             0.182
13             2.559 2006-10-13             0.186
14             2.626 2006-10-16             0.207
15             2.659 2006-10-17             0.201
16             2.608 2006-10-18             0.196
17             2.610 2006-10-19             0.206
18             2.679 2006-10-20             0.199
19             2.710 2006-10-23             0.201
20             2.597 2006-10-24             0.199
```

What I want to do it to join `df1` with `df2`. In the case of only two columns I would do:

```
x = left_join(df1, df2[,2], by = c("Date" = "Date...1"))
```

But since `df2` has *n* columns with different names I find it hard to compute this function. I tried with a loop which I still don't see why it is not working. Find the loop below:

```
t = seq(1,10,2)
g = seq(1,10,2)

for(j in g) {
    for(i in 1:length(t)) {
r = left_join(df1, df2[, print(c(j, j+1))], by = c("Date" = paste0("Date...",t[i])))
}
}
```

Can anyone help me sort this out?

Thanks

**NOTE**

If implementing the solutions below (result based on the real dataset with `df2` having many more rows), this is what you get:

[image]

In other words, every observation is repetead *n* times. The expected output instead should be different. Let's take "FRBONDSWAPBREAK1Y" and "ITBONDSWAPBREAK2Y" as an example: the first one has observations in 2010, the second one in 2006. The output should be:

Date

Date...9   ITBONDSWAPBREAK2Y  FRBONDSWAPBREAK1Y
2006-09-27             0.110     NA
2006-09-28             0.117     NA
2006-09-29             0.120     NA
2006-09-30             NA        ...
2006-10-01             NA
2006-10-02             0.144
2006-10-03             0.151
2006-10-04             0.114
2006-10-05             0.174
2006-10-06             0.156
2006-10-07             NA
2006-10-08             NA
2006-10-09             0.174
2006-10-10             0.167
2006-10-11             0.193
2006-10-12             0.182
2006-10-13             0.186
2006-10-14             NA
2006-10-15              NA
2006-10-16             0.207
2006-10-17             0.201
2006-10-18             0.196
2006-10-19             0.206
2006-10-20             0.199     NA
.
.
.
2010-07-23       NA               data
2010-07-26       NA                data
2010-07-27       NA                data
2010-07-28       NA
2010-07-29       ...
2010-07-30
2010-08-02
2010-08-03
2010-08-04
2010-08-05
2010-08-06
2011-07-20
2011-07-21
2011-07-22
2011-07-25
2011-07-26
2011-07-27
2011-07-28
2011-07-29
2011-08-01       NA

Comment: yes sorry, myscopied, fixed it now

Comment: df1 contains only 1 column. What's the point of joining it?

Comment: I need to order the dataframe by daily observations so that the final dataframe looks like a daily time series with some missing observations for the date where the value is not available

Comment: Please show your expected output for the data shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the join for your goal of having a *"dataframe by daily observations so that the final dataframe looks like a daily time series with some missing observations for the date where the value is not available"*.

```
library(tidyverse)

names(df2) %>%
  matrix(ncol = 2, byrow = T) %>% # in the first column, there are date column names from df2, in the second column, there are value column names
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  transmute(
    df = df2 %>% select("Date" = V1, V2) %>% list() # selecting columns from df2 based on the column names in V1 and V2
  ) %>%
  unnest() %>% # putting the nested data.frames in a new data.frame
  tidyr::complete(Date = seq(min(Date), max(Date), by="day")) # adding missing dates
```

Comment: there is an issue with both approaches proposed. In using  `pivot_longer`, you get every observation repetead *n* times. I guess this is due to the shifting of the "Date" column

Comment: @Ronak Shah take a look at the updated post if you have time

Comment: That's exactly what I meant! Thanks a lot, super super helpful!

Comment: @Rollo99 glad I can help. Apologies for not using a join as was your original idea.

Answer (score 3):

We could get the data in long format and perform the join so we can do this in one join itself.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Date'), values_to = 'Date') %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  right_join(df1, by = 'Date')
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant but it works for your case I guess.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df2 %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("Date"), lubridate::as_date)) -> df2

df2 %>% 
  set_names(~ str_replace_all(., "\\..*", "")) -> df3

df3 %>% names() %>% 
  str_detect("Date") %>% 
  which() -> numbers

df3 %>% 
  select(1,2) -> df4

for(i in numbers[-1]){

  df4 %>% 
    full_join(df3 %>% select(i, i+1)) -> df4
}
#> Note: Using an external vector in selections is ambiguous.
#> ℹ Use `all_of(i)` instead of `i` to silence this message.
#> ℹ See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html>.
#> This message is displayed once per session.
#> Joining, by = "Date"
#> Joining, by = "Date"
#> Joining, by = "Date"
#> Joining, by = "Date"

df1 %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  left_join(df4) 
#> Joining, by = "Date"
#> # A tibble: 6,968 x 6
#>    Date       GDPWY X5Y5YINFSWAP ITBONDSWAPBREAK… FRBONDSWAPBREAK…
#>    <date>     <dbl>        <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
#>  1 2002-01-01    NA           NA               NA               NA
#>  2 2002-01-02    NA           NA               NA               NA
#>  3 2002-01-03    NA           NA               NA               NA
#>  4 2002-01-04    NA           NA               NA               NA
#>  5 2002-01-05    NA           NA               NA               NA
#>  6 2002-01-06    NA           NA               NA               NA
#>  7 2002-01-07    NA           NA               NA               NA
#>  8 2002-01-08    NA           NA               NA               NA
#>  9 2002-01-09    NA           NA               NA               NA
#> 10 2002-01-10    NA           NA               NA               NA
#> # … with 6,958 more rows, and 1 more variable: ITBONDSWAPBREAK2Y <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>